# Powershell convert Array of Objects into PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell

I would like to convert this array of objects

```
Name    CIDR
----    ----
sdc-MO  10.92.18.136/20
sdc-RM  10.77.6.34/20
```

into a single `[PSCustomObject]`

```
sdc-MO           sdc-RM
-------           -------
{10.92.18.136/20} {10.77.6.34/20}
```

Please suggest any easy way.. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting an error?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show how the array is assigned its values. Powershell arrays don't ave headers, so having Name and CIDR means that either it's not an array in the first case, or it's an array of arrays piped to format-table or something different altogether.

Comment: @vonPryz What? An array containing two objects each with a `Name` and `CIDR` property would display exactly like that by default

Answer (score 1):

Add each object to a hashtable or other dictionary dictionary type, then use the dictionary to create the object (each entry will become a separate property):

```
$array = @(
  [pscustomobject]@{ Name = 'sdc-MO'; CIDR = '10.92.18.136/20' }
  [pscustomobject]@{ Name = 'sdc-RM'; CIDR = '10.77.6.34/20' }
)

# Prepare a new dictionary to hold the properties
$newProperties = [ordered]@{}

foreach($inputObject in $array){
  # If we don't already have a property with the given name, 
  # create a new entry in the dictionary
  if(-not $newProperties.Contains($inputObject.Name)){
    $newProperties.Add($inputObject.Name, @())
  }

  # Add the `CIDR` value to the corresponding property name
  $newProperties[$inputObject.Name] += $inputObject.CIDR
}

$newObject = [pscustomobject]$newProperties
```

`$newObject` will be like what you described in the question:

```
PS C:\> $newObject

sdc-MO            sdc-RM
------            ------
{10.92.18.136/20} {10.77.6.34/20}
```

Comment: @iRon Not sure I understand what OP did wrong? His first sample is _exactly_ what you'd expect the default formatting of an array containing two objects each with a Name and CIDR property to look like.

Comment: @iRon I made a slight edit to OPs post, might do the trick :)